# Android load pdf in Webview locally from SDcard

Tags: javascript, java, android, html, webview

I am trying to load a pdf from my sd onto webview.
I know it is not possible to direct load a pdf in webview. So I have a html file which renders the file and load the pdf.

**sample from** http://www.worldwidewhat.net/2011/08/render-pdf-files-with-html5/

**Android Code**:

```
    final WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.magazineWebView);
    final ProgressBar spinner = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.magazineSpinner);

    webView.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(mgznCanZoom);
    webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });


String webPath   = "http://mysite/demo/pdf-js/index.htm"; //WORKS       
String file_name2   = "pdf-js/index.htm"; //LOAD HTML BUT NOT PDF

    String file_uri = MAGAZINE_FOLDER + file_name2;
    String sdPath = Uri.parse("file://"
                    + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + file_uri).toString();



    webView.loadUrl(sdPath); //webPath
```

> > Erros from logcat:

```
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///storage/emulated/0/MyApp/Magazine/pdf-js/compressed.tracemonkey-pldi-09.pdf. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, https.", source: file:///storage/emulated/0/MyApp/Magazine/pdf-js/index.htm (0)
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(52)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of null", source: file:///storage/emulated/0/MyApp/Magazine/pdf-js/lib/pdf.js (52)
I/AppLifecycle: onActivitySaveInstanceState
```

**But ->**
 If I store this file in the cloud and load it as above, it will work fine.
Anyone know why this wont load locally ?
Thanks guys.

P.S I know there are lot of these question online. I have looked around and not found a solution.

I am not able to use librarys like this https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview

Comment: Remove the  `file://` from that path. It should start with /storage. Moreover you could have mentioned the necessary protocol shemes. Please explain data and chrome.

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest`. Well it wants to use http.

Comment: You need the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission too.

Comment: It will be totally offline. I have all the required permissions. thanks

Comment: You should react on all my comments of course.